# nginx multiple domain configuration failed

Tags: nginx

502 bad gateway error, hmm I've no problem with my dns. I have a folder named 'app' and 'website' in my /home directory.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name dashboard.abc.com;

    location / {
        root app;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name abc.com

    location / {
        root site;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Everything make sense here, not sure which part is causing the problem

Comment: Can you clarify "failed to access it"? Have you confirmed the dns for abc.com points to that box? Does it fails if you curl the box directly, passing in the Host header?

Comment: @jdewald just can't connect, i had a 502 bad gateway error. Updated my question.

Comment: Can you update with the actual request/response cycle? Your configuration looks fine, so it would be good to see it via CURL or WGET requests. A 502 would tend to imply that it's your dashboard.abc.com URL that is failing, not the abc.com one.

Comment: @jdewald both have the same error actually.

Comment: Well one thing that is odd is that you have both a 'root' and a proxy_pass for the '/' location on dashboard.abc.com. Are you trying to proxy, or serve the app directory? I would recommend checking /usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log and see what it is complaining about?

Comment: @jdewald proxy, does that matter?

Comment: Well no reason for the "root" if you're going to proxy, I'm actually somewhat surprised it even lets you do that since proxy_pass is a "content" handler. But I would look at the error log, any 502 should end up there

Comment: You should know the `root` directive in your proxy is potentially very dangerous, regardless of whether or not it is the cause for your 502. You're telling nginx to serve everything in `app` statically.